# Route returns empty model when using find() method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a 'clock' record which contains some user settings. The record is saved in the local storage. If the page is refreshed, I don't want to create a new record all the time when I already have one.
I'm using Ember Data and LSAdapter.

My approach:
In ApplicationRoute I check if a record of type 'clock' exists.

If yes --> return firstObject as model.
If no --> create new record and return it

The simple case of always creating a new record and returning it works fine. The record becomes my model. However, as soon as I use this.find() the route returns an empty model.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model : function(){
        var length, clock;
        var self = this;

        this.store.find('clock').then(function(record){

            length = record.get("length");  // works

            if(length == 0){
                clock = self.store.createRecord('clock', {
                    soundOgg: "data/sounds/cling.ogg",
                    soundMp3: "data/sounds/cling.mp3"
                });
                console.log(clock); // prints correct object

                return clock;   // returns empty model

            } else {
                clock = record.get('firstObject');
                console.log(clock); // prints correct object

                return clock;   // returns empty model
            }    
        });    
    }
});
```

Why is it not working? Is there a better way for returning the correct model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
this.store.find('clock').then(...
```

Do this:

```
return this.store.find('clock').then(...
```

The router's `model` hook should `return` a promise.